# Can scriptures ever be properly translated into English or any other languages?

Tags: scripture

Hindu scriptures are written in Sanskrit. We know Sanskrit is a language where each word has multiple meanings. Most of us are ignorant about Sanskrit. If we translate a sanskrit word into English, then the equivalent English word will not have same synonyms as the Sanskrit word in Sanskrit have. In that case how trustworthy are any english translations since by translating into English, it just gives one meaning to the end reader? This may apply to other languages as well. What's the way out then?

Comment: The words can be but meaning and sounds of words are perfect in our language.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS you mean Sanskrit?

Comment: whatever languages we have scriptures

Comment: @AkshayKumarS I think main difficulty is with Sanskrit scriptures only especially upanishads, Gita and others also to some extent.

Comment: i think they can be translated in Hindi & other Indian languages (derived from Sanskrit) more properly than English..

Comment: As said by @YDS it is not so much of a problem if the language is based on Sanskrit (like Hindi, Bengali). But reading scriptures entirely in English can be misleading always. That's why I always buy books on scriptures only in Sanskrit-Bengali. The last option for me is Sanskrit-English.